# How to solve "TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given)"?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap

I'm getting this TypeError despite me not having any class. Why is this the case?

```
def main():
    import arcpy
    from arcpy.sa import *
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\darel\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\ArcMap_Folder"
    inRaster = "USGS_13_n36w083_20220512.tif"

    outSlope = Slope(inRaster, "PERCENT_RISE")
    outSlope.save("C:\\Users\\darel\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\ArcMap_Folder\\improv_slope.tif")

    myRemapRange = RemapRange([[0, 8, 0], [9, 999, 2]])
    outReclass_Slope = Reclassify(outSlope, "VALUE", myRemapRange,"NODATA")

    inRaster2 = outReclass_Slope
    outFocalStat = FocalStatistics(inRaster2, NbrCircle(33, "CELL"), "SUM", "NODATA")
    outFocalStat.save("C:\\Users\\darel\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\ArcMap_Folder\\improv_focal.tif")

    myRemapRange2 = RemapRange([0, 20, 400], [21, 50, 300], [51, 80, 200], [81, 100, 100])
    outReclass_Focal = Reclassify(outFocalStat, "VALUE", myRemapRange2,"NODATA")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 19, in main
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given)
```

Comment: Which line is line 19? Is there not a full traceback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `RemapRange([0, 20, 400], [21, 50, 300], [51, 80, 200], [81, 100, 100])` you're passing 4 separate arguments, but it expects 1 list of lists.

"Takes exactly 2 arguments" means `self`, which is automatically supplied, +1 other user-specified argument.  This is because `RemapRange` is a class, and it's calling `__init__()` as a class method behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the error!